# QGIS fix invalid geometry for intersection on Corine Land Cover files

Tags: qgis, intersection, invalid-data

There are many posts on this but I was wondering on which layer should I do my operations. I explain: I am using the Corine Land Cover (CLC) files for 2006 and I am just interested in one part in Germany. So I did an intersection between my layer with entire europe and the one with an adm area. In the log I can see that I have many invalid geometries and as a result I am losing a lot of objects.

How can I fix that and on which layer should I act upon (the CLC layer which is very big?)

Could it be due because the CLC files are rasters rather than vectors?

Comment: Hi, I am working on vectors, I have been checking validity under the vector tool and I have many invalid geometries. The problem reported is "Ring Self-intersection" and this prevent me to be capable to do calculation on my file...

Comment: I have a very heavy file (Corine land cover) but when I clip it with a polygon I lose geometries due to the error I described above... therefore I need to act upon the big file but it crashes because it's too heavy... I don't know how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Fix geometries](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#fix-geometries)
- If that isnt enough you can try and buffer the output with a very small distance, or even zero